# One data set returns null for one user only on SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I am experiencing an odd situation. I have a production and test report server up and running and they have been running flawlessly for over a year. On Monday 5/20 everything was working. Beginning yesterday I began to experience a data set returning `NULL` for one user only. I have access to two domain users, one we will call `name` and one we will call `db`. The `name` user is my normal user and is what I log on to my PC with. The `db` user is the one I use for development tasks and troubleshooting. The `db` user is the one affected.

The data set in question is a very simple two line SQL select that list the company's branches for use in various reports on the report server. Here is a generic representation of that query:

```
select branchID, branchName from branch
```

This query runs in SQL Server Management Studio. Here are the things I have done to verify the scope of the issue:

I logged on to the production and development report servers with `name` and ran `Report X` that depends on the `branch` data set. The report output was correct.

I logged on to the production and development report servers with `db` and ran `Report X` and could not select a branch because no values were present in the Branch combo box.

I opened the data set in Report Builder 3.0 and executed it on both users. The `name` user got the correct result set back but the `db` user did not.

I asked a couple of users that I trust to run `Report X` and it ran fine for them.

I asked my network admin to double check domain permissions for `db` and they looked fine.

I double checked the ODBC driver I use for the report server and the connection is good.

I am at a loss as to what to check. Any suggestions?

**Edit 1: I also ran `Report Y` with the `db` user. This report does not use the branch data set and it ran fine. The only data set that has an issue is the branch data set.**

**Edit 2: I logged on to SSMS with the problem user and ran select * from branch and the result set was empty. In addition I ran select * from equipment and the result set was valid - around 54,000 records. So it appears to be a permission issue on some tables. The only one I know about is the branch table.**

Comment: I don't have any specific suggestions, but have you used SQL Profiler to verify that the same SQL is being executed for both users? It might also help to clarify what a "data set returning NULL" means: a completely empty result set, or one with NULL in specific rows/columns, or something else?

Comment: Returning `NULL` in this instance means that the data set is empty. When I select `Edit in Report Builder` for the data set the report builder shows the SQL statement and when I click the run button the result is nothing. However if I run the same data set in the report builder for the `name` user it returns the correct data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to permissions. We are using Windows authentication on the database. So my "db" user was just a domain user. Since domain users were allowed to access the database it was never an issue. However during the last software upgrade the branch table was replaced by a view. The construction of the view prevents domain users from seeing the contents of the view unless they are also a database user. The fix was to create a "db" user on the database.